# WooCommerce: same stock for different products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a shop where you can print stuff on products. Now I have a Product for Image-Printing and one for Text-Printing but both of them go to either a black or a white cup.

So basically I have the following products:

- Black cup with text
- White cup with text
- Black cup with image
- White cup with image

Now when someone orders e.g. a "Black cup with image", I need to reduce the stock for "Black cup with text" too because its the the same "base product".

How could this be done? I can't get it working with variations because too many things differ between the products.

Comment: Why not use a variable product?

Answer (score 0):

what about creating 4 products:
text,
image,
black,
white

text and image will be infinite with as many settings as you need. plus customer will have to choose from white/black cup product (which will hold stock management)

otherwise you will have to tweak add_action('woocommerce_reduce_order_stock', 'action_woocommerce_reduce_order_stock', 10, 1 );

It also depends on how many products page has etc...

But I am new to WP so...